# Given $A=\langle yz^2,-3xz^2, 2xyz\rangle$ and $\phi = xyz$, evaluate $A .\nabla $ and $(A \times \nabla)\phi$

Tags: derivatives, vectors, cross-product

I know $\nabla = \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\rangle$ and $\nabla . A $ and $\nabla \times A$ makes sense to me but how do we evaluate $A.\nabla$ and $A\times \nabla $?

Comment: $$A \cdot \nabla = A_{1} \partial_{x} + A_{2} \partial_y + A_{3} \partial_z$$ and $$A \times \nabla = (A_{2} \partial_z - A_{3} \partial_y, A_{3} \partial_x - A_{1} \partial_z, A_{1} \partial_y - A_{2} \partial_x)$$ where the $A_{i}$ are the components of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Things become clearer when we focuse on the nature of the object.

**Configuring**

$$ f_1: (x,y,z)\to yz^2 $$
$$ f_2: (x,y,z)\to -3xz^2 $$
$$ f_3: (x,y,z)\to 2xyz $$
$$ \phi : (x,y,z) \to xyz$$
So A is a function

$$A\in{\mathbb{R}^3}^{\mathbb{R}^3}$$

$$ A=(f_1,f_2,f_3) $$

Thus the operators are well defined

$$ A\cdot \nabla $$ 
$$ A\times \nabla $$

is a function of function i.e. and generally speaking an operator. Applying to $\phi$

$$ A\cdot \nabla(\phi)=f_1 \partial_1\phi + f_2 \partial_2\phi + f_3 \partial_3\phi $$
$$ (A \times \nabla)(\phi)=<(f_2 \partial_3 - f_3 \partial_2)\phi \ ; \ (f_3 \partial_1 - f_1 \partial_3)\phi \ ; \ (f_2 \partial_1 - f_1 \partial_2)\phi > $$

There you go !

**Comment**

As you see that , for instance $$A \times \nabla $$ is an operator , so it is an object, a process, an operator ready to be applied to a function.

Comment: One thing, $A.\nabla$ will  be $f_{1} \partial_{1} + f_{2} \partial_{2} + f_{3} \partial_{3}$ and won't involve $\phi$ right?

Comment: Yes exactly ! Then you can apply $\phi$